# Having trouble with IF NOT statments work in Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

this might be an easy fix but I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to get this IF statement, if the cell is not FALSE to return value, else to return a certain string. I've tried a couple of ways but I can't make the right combination. And I have a similar issue with excluding the FALSE value from a UNIQUE search statement.
This is the [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwbNk-6HWi3R7pDNMoWyfzPAlSGrgavLPHw-DPub6vg/edit#gid=0). Sorry if I'm missing on smth very obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your concern in setting a value if the cell is NOT FALSE, you can use this formula in Row 2:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",if(A2:A=FALSE,"Blank",iferror(year(to_date(datevalue(A2:A))),"No year found")),""))
```

### What it does?

- Check if cell value is FALSE, If yes, set cell value to "Blank", else convert the date string to value using [datevalue()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en). Then use [to_date()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239?hl=en) to convert date value into a date object. Use [year()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061?hl=en) to get the year. Use [iferror()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) to set a default value if the formula encountered an error (when your string is not a valid date string)
- Loop each row using [arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

### Output:

[image]

---

Regarding filtering your data without `FALSE`:

```
=filter(A2:A,A2:A <> FALSE)
```

### What it does?

- Using [filter()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en), filter the data if the cell value is not `FALSE`

### Output:

[image]

### Note:

You can also use UNIQUE() once you filter your data

```
=unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A <> FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use DATE / TO_DATE before. I see it also works in my case without the to_date